# Quarkus High RAM usage on empty project with just some entities

Tags: quarkus

I have been testing Quarkus, to check if it's worth the replacing cost, when running an empty Quarkus project with only `resteasy` and `jsonb` , the RAM usage is of just **5MB**. But after adding only some entities from a big project, the project has grown to **100MB**, which I find as an abusive usage, as in the Spring one, the full project is using **180MB**.

Reproduction repository: https://github.com/KevinGuancheDarias/quarkus-owge-poo

running natively steps (requires `docker`)

```sh
$ mvn package -Pnative -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true -DskipTests
$ docker build --no-cache -f src/main/docker/Dockerfile.native -t quarkus/test .
$ docker run -i --rm -p 8080:8080 quarkus/test
```

Command used to test the sizes

```sh
docker stats 2985d8366e51 32db5040f6e7
```

Sample output where owge_all_dockerized.... is the full project running in Docker and suspicious_borg is the quarkus test
[image: The stats]

Quarkus extensions: `agroal, cdi, hibernate-orm, hibernate-orm-panache, jdbc-mysql, mutiny, narayana-jta, resteasy, resteasy-jsonb, smallrye-context-propagation`

Is this the expected RAM usage?

Update: Removing only `hibernate ORM`, but preserving `agroal` and `jdbc-mysql`, makes the memory go down to **6MB**

Update: Please note, that both the quarkus test and the full project running in Spring boot are immediately started, and stopped, no time for GC to fill up the memory

Thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 1):

Native graalvm execution has a different kind of memory management than when running traditional Java/jar.

Details are to be found in [the official docs](https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/native-image/optimizations-and-performance/MemoryManagement/) but basically it will grow in memory more aggressively but you can limit it by adding `-mx 10m` for example. Then it will not grow beyond 10 mb - which if is enough for your app will be fine.

Of course if your app *actually* needs more then increase it.

Comment: Thank you, but, why goes it so high with Hibernate ORM?, If I hard limit the max ram only to avoid allocation of a lot of potentially unused memory, my application may get out of  memory when it really requires it.

Comment: there currently is a silly bug with metadata handling - I'm investigating, will post a link to the issue when I know more. Shouldn't take long!

Comment: @KevinGuancheDarias read the details in the url for details. basically if you this process on a laptop with plenty of memory it will be more agressive to grab memory as it is generally more performant; but if you run in a more limited setup (i.e. in a cluster/container) it will adjust its memory grabbing. Yes, there could be bugs as sanne refers to but I would say try making sure you don't give the process access to too much memory if you want to test/compare memory usage.

Comment: But why just adding Hibernate makes the memory usage grow up 95MB more?, I understand that, while you use the app, it may collect the objects, instead of freeing them, but I'm talking of an application that is running completely idle, no objects been created, only the quarkus service starting up. I think it's more something like @Sanne says. A bug with how Hibernate proccess the metainformation. If I remove the Hibernate and use regular JDBC, RAM usage increases with the time, which is obviously as the GC likes to full the heap before "stoping the world". Best regards!

Comment: Ack. I thought you had run for a bit. If it's pure startup then yes Sanne is in the right track

Comment: @MaxRydahlAndersen Thanks for your help anyway, I have updated the question to clarify that point